# PowerShell function parameters syntax

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Why do the [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx) outside of the function work different than inside of the function?

It seems like somehow the parameters variables are changing from what I declared it to be...

```sh
function a([string]$svr, [string]$usr) {
    $x = "$svr\$usr"
    Write-Host $x
}

$svr = 'abc'
$usr = 'def'

Write-Host "$svr\$usr"  # abc\def
a($svr, $usr)           # abc def
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't call functions or cmdlets in PowerShell with parentheses and commas (only do this in method calls)!

When you call `a($svr, $usr)` you're passing an array with the two values as the single value of the first parameter. It's equivalent to calling it like `a -svr $svr,$usr` which means the `$usr` parameter is not specified at all. So now `$x` equals the string representation of the array (a join with spaces), followed by a backslash, followed by nothing.

Instead call it like this:

```powershell
a $svr $usr
a -svr $svr -usr $usr
```

Comment: I use Powershell every day, and every now and then I make this exact mistake and spend 10+ minutes pulling my hair out.

Comment: Oh and I want to point out that using `Set-StrictMode` will help you catch this mistake.