Penalty on not closing recordset or connection?
I have multiple powershell scripts that have to get settings from a MS Access database. I do this inline with this code:
$objConnection = New-Object -combody ADODB.Connection
$objRecordset = New-Object -combody ADODB.Recordset
$objConnection.Open($myDatabase)
$objRecordset.Open($MyQuery, $objConnection , $adOpenStatic, $adLockOptimistic)

# do stuff

$objRecordset.Close()
$objConnection.Close()

The first and the last part is always the same, so for brevity and ease of maintaining I want to put the first in a function:
function GetSettings(myQuery) {
    $objConn = New-Object -combody ADODB.Connection
    $objRec = New-Object -combody ADODB.Recordset
    $objConn.Open($myDatabase)
    $objRec.Open($myQuery, $objConn, $adOpenStatic, $adLockOptimistic)

    return $objRec
}

And then just call it:
$objRecordset = GetSettings($MyQuery)

But this does not close the recordset or the connection in the function. Is this a problem or will they get closed automatically after exiting the function or even exiting the powershell script? This will be running multiple times per day, I don't want to risk filling up memory or causing other issues.
I've tried assigning $objRec to some other variable $myReturnRec = $objRec and returning that, but that does not work, $myReturnRec remains null after the assignment.

Have you tried $objRecClone=$objRec.Clone();  return objRecClone? Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/clone-method-ado

I tried that now, but unlike the comment on that page that "Closing the original Recordset does not close its copies", I find that closing the original recordset does also close its copies. When I close the original recordset, the clone is also empty.

what version of Powershell are you using? That might be important

5.1 build 19041 revision 4522 on a windows 10 Cloud PC (corporate environment, I can't change anything).

There is a connection pool so you can connect to multiple database without closing.  A connection will automatically close after you use up the max connections in the pool.

Aside, note that while $objConnection.Open($myDatabase) with ( ... ) and commas is correct for .Net methods, your GetSettings($MyQuery) with ( ... )is not correct for invoking PowerShell cmdlets / functions - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941644/powershell-function-parameters-syntax (and lots of other duplicates) for the problems this causes with multiple parameters...
